# How to pass all props to styled component in React Native with TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, styled-components

I have a styled component:

```
const Wrapper = styled.View`
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
`;
```

I have a component which is using this styled component:

```
interface ProfileInfoBar extends ViewProps {}
const ProfileInfoBar: React.FC<ProfileInfoBar> = ({ ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <Wrapper {...rest}>
      <Avatar firstname="A" lastname="B" size={60} />
    </Wrapper>
  );
};
```

But I am getting an error when trying to pass `rest` to `Wrapper`:

> No overload matches this call.   Overload 1 of 2, '(props:
> Pick<Pick<ViewProps & RefAttributes, "hitSlop" | "onLayout" |
> "pointerEvents" | "removeClippedSubviews" | "style" | "testID" |
> "nativeID" | ... 48 more ... | "key"> & Partial<...>, "hitSlop" | ...
> 54 more ... | "key"> & { ...; } & { ...; } & { ...; }):
> ReactElement<...>', gave the following error.
> Type '{ children: Element[]; hitSlop?: Insets | undefined; onLayout?: ((event: LayoutChangeEvent) => void) | undefined;
> pointerEvents?: "none" | "auto" | "box-none" | "box-only" | undefined;
> ... 48 more ...; accessibilityIgnoresInvertColors?: boolean |
> undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'Pick<Pick<ViewProps &
> RefAttributes, "hitSlop" | "onLayout" | "pointerEvents" |
> "removeClippedSubviews" | "style" | "testID" | "nativeID" | ... 48
> more ... | "key"> & Partial<...>, "hitSlop" | ... 54 more ... |
> "key">'.
> Types of property 'style' are incompatible.

[image]

I can't understand how to pass all props to styled component. Any ideas?

Comment: Try this `{...{rest}}` ?

Comment: @AshutoshDubey Not sure that this is can be a solution

Comment: You are using the same name `ProfileInfoBar` to describe both the component itself and the interface of its props.  But I am not able to reproduce your error.

Comment: @LindaPaiste Thanks, fixed it, but I still have TS error :(

Comment: It is something with style prop, because if I am writing `{ style, ...rest }` then everything is ok

Comment: I looked at this again and I'm not able to reproduce your error, at least not on CodeSandbox with react-native-web.  The `style` prop on `ProfileInfoBar` and `Wrapper` are both type `StyleProp<ViewStyle>`  If you write `<Wrapper style={style}>` and hover over it, what types are you seeing?